# Contar quantas colunas há em um arquivo CSV com C++

Tags: c++, csv

Estou fazendo um projeto de uma urna eletrônica, e para isso preciso ler um arquivo csv onde há as informações sobre cada candidato.

Como esse arquivo csv tem muitas informações que não são relevantes, eu decidir utilizar somente determinadas colunas do arquivo csv, por exemplo: NM_CANDIDATO, NM_PARTIDO, ...

A solução que pensei foi iniciar um contador para salvar o "índice" das colunas desejadas, porém não consigo determinar o final da primeira linha, e o índice continua sendo incrementado com todos os dados.

```
"DT_GERACAO"; "SG_PARTIDO"  ;  "HH_GERACAO"
"03/09/2018"; "DC"          ;   "08:01:43"  
"03/09/2018"; "MDB"         ;   "08:01:43"
"03/09/2018"; "PODE"        ;   "08:01:43"
```

Nesse exemplo, somente a coluna SG_PARTIDO me interessa. Assim, um contador i é inicializado i=1 e durante o getline() da primeira linha é incrementado. Quando uma coluna desejada é encontrada, a posição dessa coluna é salva, para que quando o contador for inicializado i=1 na próxima linha alguma ação seja realizada na coluna desejada.

O código que escrevi é esse abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("presidentes.csv");

    if(!file.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"Erro! Não foi possível abrir esse arquvio"<<'\n';
    }

    string buffer;
    int i=1 p_SG_PARTIDO = 0;

    while(!file.eof())
    {
        getline(file, buffer, ';');

        if(buffer == "SG_PARTIDO" || i == p_SG_PARTIDO)
        {
            p_SG_PARTIDO = i;
            cout << buffer;
        }

        i++;

        if(buffer == "\n") i=1;
    }

    file.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Essa condição do buffer nunca é verdadeira. Desconfio que o motivo seja uma dupla aspas, ""SG_PARTIDO"". Quando eu removi o primeiro e o ultimo carácter, antes da comparação, essa condição se torna verdadeira, mas continuo com o problema de não saber quando a primeira linha acaba.

O código que retiro o carácter é esse abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("presidentes.csv");

    if(!file.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"Erro! Não foi possível abrir esse arquvio"<<'\n';
    }

    string buffer;
    int i=1;
    int p_ds_cargo = 0;

    while(!file.eof())
    {
        getline(file, buffer, ';');

        if(buffer[0]=='"') // remover """"
        {
            buffer.erase(0,1);
            buffer.erase(buffer.size() - 1);
        }

        if(buffer == "DT_GERACAO")
        {
            p_ds_cargo = i;
            cout << buffer << endl;   
        }

        if(buffer == "\n") i = 1;

        i++;
    }



    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Eu agradeço desde já se alguém souber uma maneira mais fácil de ler somente colunas específicas em um arquivo csv.

O link para o csv que estou usando é esse:
https://gitlab.com/oofga/eps/eps_2018_2/ep1/raw/master/data/consulta_cand_2018_BR.csv?inline=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problemas

O arquivo csv tem todos os conteudos dentro de aspas duplas(`"`) logo a comparação que tem nunca irá funcionar:

```
if(buffer == "SG_PARTIDO"
```

Contornar esse problema passa por comparar com as aspas:

```
if(buffer == "\"SG_PARTIDO\""
```

Ou remover as aspas do valor lido antes de comparar:

```
if(buffer.substr(1, buffer.size() - 2) == "SG_PARTIDO"
```

No entanto o teste de mudança de linha também não funciona:

```
if(buffer == "\n") i=1;
```

Pois a leitura com `getline` é sempre feita até ao `;` logo nunca irá ler apenas a quebra de linha.

### Outra Abordagem

Sugiro outra abordagem ao problema, que acaba por ser mais robusta e permitir-lhe também obter dados de múltiplas colunas, algo que ia ficar mais complicado da forma que estava a fazer.

A ideia é:

- Ler cada linha normalmente com `getline` prevalecendo o delimitador normal `\n`
- Obtem cada coluna de cada linha através de `getline` mudando o delimitador para `;`
- Armazena cada linha num `vector<string>` e todas as linhas num `vector<vector<string> >`

### Leitura

Existem muitas maneiras de tentar ler um csv numa matriz, mas optei por uma que considero simples e que lhe permite obter a informação que pretende.

Implementação:

```
int main()
{
    //...
    string buffer;
    vector<vector<string> > linhas; //vetor de vetor para toads as linhas

    while(!file.eof())
    {
        getline(file, buffer); //ler cada linha
        stringstream ss(buffer); //colocar a linha lida num stringstream

        vector<string> linha; //iniciar o vetor da linha
        while (getline(ss, buffer, ';')) { //ler cada coluna
            linha.push_back(buffer); //adicionar ao vetor da linha
        }

        linhas.push_back(linha); 
    }
    //...
```

Note que fiz uso tanto de `vector` como `stringstream` e por isso precisei de dois `includes` adicionais:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
```

Outra possibilidade aqui é adicionar apenas os textos já sem as aspas, que irá facilitar mais à frente quando precisar de mostrar e comparar, trocando `linha.push_back(buffer);` por `linha.push_back(buffer.substr(1, buffer.size() - 2);`, mas no resto da resposta assumo que foram adicionados com as aspas.

### Utilização de uma coluna

Uma forma ingénua e não muito eficiente ainda que simples de obter apenas informação para todas as linhas referentes à coluna `SG_PARTIDO` é:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < linhas.size(); ++i){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < linhas[i].size(); ++j){
        //se na primeira linha desta coluna tem SG_PARTIDO
        if (linhas[0][j] == "\"SG_PARTIDO\""){ 
            cout << linhas[i][j].substr(1, linhas[i][j].size() - 2); //mostrar sem as "
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Naturalmente isto assume que a primeira linha tem os cabeçalhos do csv. Utilizei o [`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) para mostrar apenas o conteúdo excluindo as aspas duplas.

Exemplo de teste na minha máquina:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Utilização de múltiplas colunas

Se tiver interessado em várias colunas pode construir um vetor com os indices das colunas que está interessado e depois apenas iterar sobre esses:

```
vector<int> colunasRelevantes;
for (size_t i = 0; i < linhas[0].size(); ++i){
    string nomeCol = linhas[0][i].substr(1, linhas[0][i].size() - 2);
    if (nomeCol == "SG_PARTIDO" || nomeCol == "NM_CANDIDATO" || nomeCol == "NM_PARTIDO"){
        colunasRelevantes.push_back(i);
    }
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < linhas.size(); ++i){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < colunasRelevantes.size(); ++j){
        int coluna = colunasRelevantes[j];
        string texto = linhas[i][coluna].substr(1, linhas[i][coluna].size() - 2);
        cout << texto << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

É importante mencionar que tive que remover a ultima linha em branco do arquivo para não dar erro a aceder a colunas que não existem.

Em C++11 estes *loops* ficam mais simples, mas não o fiz inicialmente para não estar já a mostrar sintaxe que possa ser nova. Ainda assim vou deixar na mesma para ficar como referência:

```
//Esta parte fica igual
vector<int> colunasRelevantes;
for (size_t i = 0; i < linhas[0].size(); ++i){
    string nomeCol = linhas[0][i].substr(1, linhas[0][i].size() - 2);
    if (nomeCol == "SG_PARTIDO" || nomeCol == "NM_CANDIDATO" || nomeCol == "NM_PARTIDO"){
        colunasRelevantes.push_back(i);
    }
}

//Aqui c++ enhanced for loop
for (auto linha : linhas){
    for (auto coluna: colunasRelevantes){
        string texto = linha[coluna].substr(1, linha[coluna].size() - 2);
        cout << texto << "\t\t\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Se precisar de utilizar muitas colunas então fica mais fácil de utilizar um vetor para esses nomes e construir os indices com base num duplo `for`:

```
vector<string> nomesColunasRelevantes = {"SG_PARTIDO", "NM_CANDIDATO", "NM_PARTIDO"};
vector<int> colunasRelevantes;
for (size_t i = 0; i < linhas[0].size(); ++i){
    string nomeCol = linhas[0][i].substr(1, linhas[0][i].size() - 2);
    for (string nome : nomesColunasRelevantes){
        if (nome == nomeCol){
            colunasRelevantes.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}
```

### Contar colunas

Agora fica igualmente fácil de responder à questão que tem no titulo da pergunta:

> Contar quantas colunas há em um arquivo CSV com C++

Basta aceder ao `size()` de qualquer uma das linhas:

```
cout << linhas[0].size();
```

Que dá `58` para o arquivo apresentado.

Comment: Gostei muito dessa nova maneira de ler as colunas relevantes!! Muitíssimo obrigado, você abriu minha mente!!

Comment: @DurvalCarvalho Sem problema estamos cá para ajudar :)